# SSRS grouping and total sum in tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

Kindly help me with the following query,
i have my a table as below,

```
PID   ID Date              Value  Weight
1     1  01-01-2014        10       0.5
2     1  01-01-2014        20       0.5
3     1  01-01-2014        30       0.5
4     1  02-01-2014        10       0.5
5     1  02-01-2014        10       0.5
6     1  02-01-2014        10       0.5
```

and i want the out put as, using SSRS

```
 ID  Date               SUM_PROD
 1  01-01-2014        30
 1  02-01-2014        15
```

Comment: In your SQL, use group by date & SUM(Value).

Comment: Thanks Aditya, Can you help me in getting the output using SSRS Tablix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group properties in your tablix.

[image]

Then in Group properties window,

[image]

Then simply display your field in your tablix like,

[image]